# Sticky headers with overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a [table](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-xl88sr?file=/src/App.js) where I want to make the header and first column sticky (as shown in the example).

It works as intended, until I add `overflow-x: scroll;` (uncomment line 3 in `styles.css`). `overflow-x: scroll` retains the first columns stickiness but breaks the top headers stickiness.

*A solution I tried but doesn't quite work:*

I've read into this topic a bit and found an [article](https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526) that describes a solution to this exact problem. The article suggests extracting your headers into a separate `div` and then using a JS scroll sync library to synchronize the overflow-x scrolling of your headers and your rows ([example 1](https://codepen.io/dannievinther/pen/exvOda), [example 2](https://codepen.io/dannievinther/pen/pGdjPV)).

This solves the stickiness + overflow problem, but introduces a new problem. The column width now can't adjust based on the length of data in the cells (as it does in my initial example) and computing this manually for every column seems sketchy.

How can I add `overflow-x: scroll;` to my [table](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-xl88sr?file=/src/App.js) while retaining the following:

- Sticky header
- Sticky first column
- Column widths that adjust based on data provided
- No nested vertical scroll (the window scrollbar should be the only vertical scroll)

I'm open to hacks with JS.

EDIT: I found another article that suggests using a JS onScroll event listener to continuously translate the table headers to the top of the screen. I tried this solution and the effect is too janky to use with the amount of data I'm using.

Comment: Been digging into this more and found another [article](https://medium.com/neocoast/fixing-a-table-header-on-a-horizontally-scrolling-table-de3364610957) that suggests using JS onScroll event to apply CSS translate to continuously move the headers to the top of the screen. This seems very janky and resource intensive, so I'm still curious if there's a better solution out there.

Comment: It seems this isn't possible with pure HTML and CSS, but there must be a cleaner JS solution than that to solve it.

Comment: this might helpt you: https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526?gi=6533723cd134

Comment: Yeah that's the article linked under the "solutions I've tried" section. As mentioned, it solves some issues, but introduces the new issue of column widths needing to be predefined. I've considered using JS to calculate the max width of all cells in each column and then manually resizing the columns, but I fear that will create a janky effect as the function runs and columns are resized one by one. Doing that for many hundreds of cells seems unwieldy. Great suggestion though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do this only with the help of css.
As I can see, you are ready to answer using javascript. So I give you a simple example that can be a starting point for solving your problem.
To simplify, I use jquery. I explained the code in the comments:

```js
// run the function on load, scroll and resize window
$(window).on('load scroll resize', stickyThead)

// run the function when we scroll the table horizontally
$('.main-table').on('scroll', stickyThead)

function stickyThead() {
  const scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
  const table = $('.main-table');
  const tableOffsetTop = table.offset()?.top;
  const ths = table.find('p:first-child'); // sticky <p>'s
  
  // reset styles
  table.removeAttr('style');
  ths.removeAttr('style');
  table.find('div').removeAttr('style');
  
  // set width of columns, this is required when the sticky <p>'s is larger than the columns
  table.find('div').each( function() {
    $(this).css( 'width', $(this).innerWidth() )
  } )
  
  // if the table is outside the window
  if ( scrollTop > tableOffsetTop + table.find('.sticky-column').innerHeight() - ths.eq(0).innerHeight() ) {
    return;
  }
  
  // if <p>'s need to stick
  if ( scrollTop > tableOffsetTop ) {
    // this is height compensation for sticky <p>'s
    table.css( 'padding-top', ths.innerHeight() );
    // add position and width to <p>'s
    ths.each( function() {
      const th = $(this);
      th.css({
        left: th.offset().left,
        top: 0,
        position: 'fixed',
        width: th.outerWidth(),
      })
    } )
  }
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.main-table {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.sticky-header {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: turquoise;
  z-index: 40;
}

.sticky-column {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: magenta;
  z-index: 50;
}

.cell {
  padding: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"><p>Dummy text</p><div class="main-table"><div class="sticky-column"><p class="cell sticky-header">1JiTVTg</p><p class="cell">GtA7a0N8K</p><p class="cell">MB5oKxbUR6Y</p><p class="cell">ZWtc1</p><p class="cell">31QDrd</p><p class="cell">yw2Z</p><p class="cell">UiHk7x</p><p class="cell">zVPZ</p><p class="cell">vhgbN</p><p class="cell">Ydbzicn</p><p class="cell">YiJjYMT</p></div><div class=""><p class="cell sticky-header">s8TSjT68YyU</p><p class="cell">9JnL8L</p><p class="cell">HzUk</p><p class="cell">4IdWh3q</p><p class="cell">Kc1CX70xcIs</p><p class="cell">Ss9oiMY2</p><p class="cell">8H1GMiGDW</p><p class="cell">1xrOu</p><p class="cell">VSDSeXM</p><p class="cell">iEymSCkvj</p><p class="cell">uMIDtC</p></div><div class=""><p class="cell sticky-header">pvB</p><p class="cell">HdvwQ8yh</p><p class="cell">rvDKoRY</p><p class="cell">AQKUrA1Dv6</p><p class="cell">uKwwbS1pu9j06Z</p><p class="cell">G182h</p><p class="cell">iC1B5R</p><p class="cell">QbiOnTiUtf</p><p class="cell">FT0eiDl5y</p><p class="cell">76GBz</p><p class="cell">Do1en</p></div><div class=""><p class="cell sticky-header">4YUuE</p><p class="cell">wBFsCdkZvW0X</p><p class="cell">NUrr45i</p><p class="cell">KiLxXCV</p><p class="cell">FA9QPt</p><p class="cell">XvUugajr3</p><p class="cell">3G8MpDc</p><p class="cell">V8XjP</p><p class="cell">GFCz</p><p class="cell">Vku74Q</p><p class="cell">QZ24q</p></div><div class=""><p class="cell sticky-header">ey2CDWFSP</p><p class="cell">iZdyg</p><p class="cell">Q5iSWKGEZrE1MC</p><p class="cell">jAVApI</p><p class="cell">vVUpQPUlK</p><p class="cell">Y3UU1rNfRJ9</p><p class="cell">I1EehdLNeKAm</p><p class="cell">ZVmw5</p><p class="cell">xLpcG</p><p class="cell">uLInezZpkdu</p><p class="cell">nIbgn4E</p></div><div class=""><p class="cell sticky-header">h5hWoN8l</p><p class="cell">BQoKq</p><p class="cell">hICAcQGa</p><p class="cell">jrEyJ72</p><p class="cell">vIOylI2xU</p><p class="cell">9f0BmoeNiZ</p><p class="cell">0Wq8</p><p class="cell">tjIKvbRcVP1</p><p class="cell">uorsJnq</p><p class="cell">9tz</p><p class="cell">Xm1Ke1OS7nKzc6KI</p></div><div class=""><p class="cell sticky-header">FADpx</p><p class="cell">2xk4HhRT</p><p class="cell">QcaMZYp</p><p class="cell">hROAxYlQ</p><p class="cell">5NHKaEe</p><p class="cell">YRo0X6ZQw</p><p class="cell">GpmLrq4BFqcN</p><p class="cell">8NyE94ajy</p><p class="cell">zYrHH7v6pCA</p><p class="cell">v8dq</p><p class="cell">nmoOrt</p></div><div class=""><p class="cell sticky-header">lSUrt</p><p class="cell">tnpvvP</p><p class="cell">ryPKEDeM</p><p class="cell">Ai3W</p><p class="cell">MvIUC</p><p class="cell">ZTYuNW</p><p class="cell">Xk7LgT</p><p class="cell">rYnk</p><p class="cell">MvpcLv</p><p class="cell">raauY0YsB5qM</p><p class="cell">3jse34Um8Z3x</p></div><div class=""><p class="cell sticky-header">mjLDwY8btQIB</p><p class="cell">frxWC</p><p class="cell">L3RClcH</p><p class="cell">oGjKldt</p><p class="cell">jaGG3obzxA</p><p class="cell">44ZjYDgou</p><p class="cell">5rPH</p><p class="cell">iKewVqO</p><p class="cell">gdQh8FA</p><p class="cell">JP4Ki</p><p class="cell">2TyjNsgs</p></div><div class=""><p class="cell sticky-header">9QxHDGt0tq</p><p class="cell">gSkQw1JnfZJb</p><p class="cell">kTtc6FLxG</p><p class="cell">HKx5AXtGjBZm</p><p class="cell">veL2fU</p><p class="cell">vSCs8Ci</p><p class="cell">ZOBmoMK</p><p class="cell">alwVgVpuZ</p><p class="cell">laiLIFS</p><p class="cell">AWQjaN</p><p class="cell">iptu2</p></div><div class=""><p class="cell sticky-header">8aop4</p><p class="cell">adJJAaaF</p><p class="cell">2344jI5LI</p><p class="cell">H3GO2X7v5</p><p class="cell">Rkn6RvJ</p><p class="cell">2fM</p><p class="cell">uF9YtzmZ</p><p class="cell">VYGm4gx01</p><p class="cell">DB5kksTGxYx5b</p><p class="cell">H6Tl</p><p class="cell">UMpEuKrenn</p></div></div><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p><p>Dummy text</p></div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution. A good starting point I think. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired outcome of having a sticky header and first column while adding `overflow-x: scroll` to your table, you can use a combination of CSS and JavaScript. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

HTML:

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <!-- Add more header columns if needed -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Row 1</th>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <!-- Add more data columns if needed -->
      </tr>
      <!-- Add more rows of data if needed -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS (styles.css):

```css
.table-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: auto;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

th:first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

td:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
const tableContainer = document.querySelector('.table-container');
tableContainer.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  const translate = `translate(${this.scrollLeft}px, ${this.scrollTop}px)`;
  this.querySelector('thead').style.transform = translate;
  this.querySelector('th:first-child').style.transform = translate;
  const firstColumnCells = this.querySelectorAll('td:first-child');
  firstColumnCells.forEach(cell => cell.style.transform = translate);
});
```

Explanation:

1. The `.table-container` div wraps the table and provides the scrolling behavior.
2. The `position: sticky` property is used to make the header and first column stick to their respective positions.
3. The JavaScript code listens for the `scroll` event on the `.table-container` div and applies a transformation to the header and first column elements, syncing their position with the scroll amount.

This approach ensures that the header and first column remain sticky while allowing horizontal scrolling and automatic adjustment of column widths based on the content length.

Remember to include the CSS and JavaScript code in your project and adjust it according to your specific table structure.

Comment: Yeah, this is the solution mentioned in my comment above, using translate. I tried it last night and it works with small amounts of data like in this example, but the translate effect stutters as you add more rows/columns. I wouldn't consider this to be useable in production in my case unfortunately. It is a good suggestion though.

Answer (score -1):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

th {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There's no horizontal scroll on this table. Appreciate the effort though